# In Rails, how to count the number of associated records in a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model named `Awardunit`. `Awardunit` have many `Awardleaders`. One Award unit can have one or many Award leaders.

If I get all the record or search and get a collection of records to a variable named `awardunits` how can I count the number of `Awardleaders` in all the units in this collection?

Here's what I did :

```
 @leaders = 0
 @awardunits.each do |unit|
      @leaders = @leaders + unit.awardleaders.size
 end
```

Again to count the disabled leaders I use this :

```
  @disabledleaders = 0
  @awardunits.each do |unit|
     @disabledleaders = @disabledleaders + unit.awardleaders.where(disabled: true).size
  end
```

If I use this, it will have to go through all the records every time the page loads. Isn't there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make counting the associations cheap by adding a counter cache:

```
class AwardUnit << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :award_units
end

class AwardLeader << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :award_unit, counter_cache: true
end
```

Now add a new column called `award_leaders_count` to your `AwardUnit` table in a new migration:

```
  def change
    add_column :award_units, :award_leaders_count, :integer, default: 0

    AwardUnit.all.each do |unit|
      AwardUnit.reset_counters(unit.id, :award_leaders)
    end
  end
```

Rails will now automatically cache the number of award_leaders for every `AwardUnit` and `@my_award_unit.award_leaders.count` will give you the count without running another database query.

By default, Rails `counter_cache` only works for all award_leaders. If you need to count only those award_leaders that have a condition, you will have to add your own counter_cache:

```
class AwardUnit << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :award_units
end

class AwardLeader << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :award_unit

  scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }

  after_save :update_counter_cache
  after_destroy :update_counter_cache

  def update_counter_cache
    award_unit.update_attribute(:disabled_award_units_count, award_unit.award_leaders.disabled.count)
  end
end
```

migration:

```
  def change
    add_column :award_units, :disabled_award_leaders_count, :integer, default: 0

    AwardUnit.all.each do |unit|
      unit.update_attribute(:disabled_award_units_count, unit.award_leaders.disabled.count)
    end
  end
```

Now, when you have an array of `AwardUnit`s, getting their combined count of disabled award leaders is as simple as

```
@award_units = AwardUnit.limit(5).to_a # or a similar query
@award_units.inject(0){|sum,unit| sum + unit.disabled_award_leaders_count }
```

Comment: Thanks! I found the Bullet gem and it also told me to use counter cache!

Comment: I've run into issues with migrationg counter cache. When you have the counter cache options in the model, it creates barriers to migrating files. I have to remove them from the model, run migrations, then add them back into the model. Is there a less annoying way to do this?

Comment: @gwho what kind of issues?

Comment: I described them right after that sentence :P The problem of specifying `counter_cache: true` in the model preventing migrations from running, and having to temporarily remove that specification in the model, run the migration, then add it back into the model.

Comment: @gwho I get that :) The question is what error messages you receive exactly.

Comment: Ah the question wasn't clear to me. `favorites_count` is marked as read only

Comment: @gwho at first glance I would say that problem is only tangentially related to this. Please open a new question including all details that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can eager load `Awardleaders` when fetching `Awardunit`s, so you don't have to execute a count query for every `Awardunit`, like this:

```
@awardunits = Awardunit.includes(:awardleaders).where('awardleaders.disabled = ?', true) # the rest of the query
```

Or, you can query the count directly like this:

```
@leaders = Awardleader.where('awardunit_id IN (?)', @awardunits.map(&:id)).where(:disabled => true).count
```

Answer (score 1):

This will run Database query only once

```
Awardunit.includes(:awardleaders).map {|award_unit| award_unit.awardleaders.size}.inject(0){|sum,item| sum + item }
```